# Поддержка Samsung

Tags: android

Как вы думаете, стоит ли для Самсунгов в манифест приложения добавить разрешение?

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы используете в своем приложении библиотеки от Samsung, то добавляйте, в других ситуациях непонятен смысл добавления этого разрешения

Comment: в гуугл консоли в отчетах об ошибках - ошибки чаще всего возникают на самсунгах

Comment: @Hellraiser, и в отчётах упоминается это разрешение? Надо выявлять проблему и устранять, а не пихать наугад "авось поможет".

Comment: на иностранных ресурсах когда-то встречал информацию о том, что как раз из-за данного разрешения падало приложение на самсунгах, на сколько помню, там решалось все с помощью обновления библиотек от самсунга